# SEO url gives 404-error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am pretty new to codeigniter. I do know php.

How can I accomplish to load the right view?

My url: /blog/this-is-my-title

I’ve told the controller something like

if end($this->uri->segment_array()) does exist in DB then load this data into some view.

I am getting an 404-error everytime I access /blog/whatever

What am i seeing wrong?

Comment: give us code you are currently using if you want specific help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you're using routing, the url `/blog/this-is-my-title` will always 404 because CI is looking for a method called `this-is-my-title`, which of course doesn't exist.

A quick fix is to put your post display code in to another function and edit the URLs to access posts from say: `/blog/view/the-post-title`

A route like:

`$route['blog/(:any)'] = "blog/view/$1";`

may also achieve what you want, if you want the URI to stay as just `/blog/this-is-my-title'

Answer (score 1):

The may be more possibilities:

1. The most common - mod_rewrite is not active
2. .htaccess is not configured correctly (if u didn't edited it try /blog/index.php/whatever)
3. The controller does not exist or is placed in the wrong folder

   Suggestion: if you only need to change data use another view in the same controller

   if (something)
   {

   $this->load->view('whatever');

   }

   else

   {
   $this->load->view('somethingelse');
   }

   If none of those works post a sample of code and configuration of .htaccess and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to remap the controller. That way, you can still use the same controller to do other things too.

No routing required!

```
enter code here
<?php
class Blog extends Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) 
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->show_post();
    }
}
function index()
{
    // show blog front page
    echo 'blog';
}
function edit()
{
    // edit blog entry
}
function category()
{
    // list entries for this category
}
function show_post()
{
    $url_title = $this->uri->segment(2);
    // get the post by the url_title
    if(NO RESULTS)
    {
        show_404();
    }
    else
    {
        // show post
    }
}
  }
 ?>
```